# How can I animate two beads each sliding on its own frictionless rail?

Tags: animation, physics, homework

I am told to animate two beads sliding on rails in Mathematica, but I am very confused on how to get a mass on a rail and it move up and down the rail.

[image: Two sticks with two masses. Mass on stick x moves up and down the stick.]

Comment: Have you been able to model a single sliding bead yet? Any code to share?

Comment: Is it 2D or 3D?

Answer (score 6):

If there are no restrictions on `r, x`, then the solution is

```
eq = {x''[t] == -k*(x[t] - r[t]*Cos[theta]), 
   r''[t] == -k*(r[t] - x[t]*Cos[theta])};

theta = Pi/4; k = 1;
ic = {x[0] == 1, r[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, r'[0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{eq, ic}, {x, r}, {t, 0, 20}]

lst = Table[
   Graphics[{{Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}], 
      Line[{{-Cos[theta], -Sin[theta]}, {Cos[theta], 
         Sin[theta]}}]}, {Green, 
      Line[{{x[t], 0}, {r[t]*Cos[theta], r[t]*Sin[theta]}} /. 
        sol]}, {Red, PointSize[.05],  Point[{x[t], 0} /. sol], 
      Point[{r[t]*Cos[theta], r[t]*Sin[theta]} /. sol]}}], {t, 0, 
    10, .1}];

 ListAnimate[lst]
```

[image: fig1]